# CQRS: Update Read-Model without Event Sourcing

Tags: c#, database-design, cqrs, nosql

We have built a CQRS-based system using a relational DB on the domain-side and a NoSQL DB on the read-side. The domain-side follows a classical, relational approach while the read-side is denormalized.
Data replication and transformation is done using events emitted by command handlers.

I have two questions regarding read-side synchronization:

- *What is the best way to completely rebuild the Read Model using the relational data on the domain-side?*

  Let's assume the Read Model is out of sync.
  But even if it is always in sync, one may want to import a test database
  or do some bulk operations. So one may want
  to run the system from an existing write-model, without having the corresponding, synchronized read-model. As we do not use Event Sourcing, there is no 
  way to replay all events.

  I currently consider a `ReadModelBuilder` which basically does a 
  SELECT * FROM on each table and convert each entity to read-side
  representation. But this introduces redundancy.
  ReadModelBuilder would need to know how the transformation is done.
  So do the Event Handlers which normally do read-side synchronization
  after a Command Handler executed some write operations.

  I thought about discarding the Event Handlers and replace them with 
  a synchronization mechanism on a per-class-level.
  E.g. instead of `FooRenamedEventHandler` renaming `foo.name`, it will
  call the `FooReadModelBuilder` which re-writes the complete `Foo` 
  instance.
  But I think this has drawbacks. The FooRenamedEventHandler can deal much
  better with redundant usages of `foo.name` within the read-model.

  **UPDATE:**
  Another approach could be to let the `ReadModelBuilder` create read-model entities by segmenting the domain instance into events, which will build the complete read-side entity when executed sequentially.
  For example:

  `Article` domain entity has a `Name` and a `Price`.
  To build the read-side model, `ReadModelBuilder` could inspect the domain entity and emit `ArticleCreatedEvent`, `ArticleRenamedEvent` and `ArticlePriceChangedEvent`. That way, the transformation logic would stay within the event handlers but would still be callable from some kind of bulk replication mechanism.

  For example the ReadModelBuilders could look like this:

_

```
interface IReadModelBuilder<TEntity>
{
    //// Returns a sequence of events which replicate the read-model 
    //// when executed by the event handlers.
    Event[] GetReplicationSequence(TEntity instance);
}
```

**END OF UPDATE**

_

- *How do you generally detect a read model which is out of sync?* Are there general best practices?

Comment: This is an interesting question. What situation have you in mind for getting out of sync?

Comment: I guess any productive usage of any serious software system experienced a situation where a database has to be swapped or bulk-transformed. It might be caused by a software bug. By a bug in the bus system. By operations failure. It might be because someone may want to deploy a test database. Or because an older backup has to be deployed. Surely one could keep both databases as a backup, but imagine the read-side backup is lost or gets corrupted.

Comment: I understand. If you don't persist the event (I.e. not using Event sourcing) then you can't easily rebuild a readmodel. Your 'rebuilder" must somehow try to reverse engineer the write model and fabricate some events which is weird because the write model could not even contain all the information as it does not need it in order to do his job.

Comment: So, my conclusion  is that, without an event store or at least an event log then you cannot rebuild your read-model. If you have some source of truth like this then you can rebuild it and even detect the out-of-sync situation by using a list of all processed event IDs in some persistence.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. We could store all events but still do not rely on Event Sourcing. However, the statement that CQRS is completely orthogonal to Event Sourcing which can be found anywhere on the internet might need some reality check. Maybe they are completely orthogonal when building an academic hello world app.

Comment: Indeed, maybe they are at 89%, not at 90 degrees :) However, CQRS without ES has this problem that you are facing. A 100% fitted for all cases solution does not exist; if you try to find one you will end up using ES. Maybe CQRS + Event logging works for you.

Comment: And, for all the situation that you have enumerated that don't imply a bug: they should not exist. The readmodel is updated in the same transaction as the writemodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't persist the event (i.e. not using `Event sourcing`) then you can't easily rebuild a `read-model`. Your `Rebuilder` must somehow try to reverse engineer the write model and fabricate some events which is weird because the `write model` could not even contain all the information as it does not need it in order to do his job.

So, my conclusion is that, without an `event store` or at least an `event log` then you cannot rebuild your `read-model`. If you have some source of truth like this then you can rebuild it and even detect the out-of-sync situation by using a list of all processed event IDs in some persistence.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about my proposal using a event-generator which reverse engineers the domain. You are right, the events may contain data which is not contained within the domain model. Even if it could be calculated using the domain data, one would introduce redundant logic between the event-generator and command handlers. Also, the implementation complexity of data schema changes grow, as every new property on the database implies extension of the event-generator. Seems like having some kind of event log is the only choice.